# A viable replacement for Quikey

Tags: crm

Our company is in the promotional products decorating industry. Specifically, we purchase raw, unimprinted disposable items (paper/foam/plastic cups, napkins, paper/plastic plates, etc.) and we print on them on-demand for our distributors. Everything we sell is in bulk, requiring a 100-piece order minimum in most cases.

We have been using a piece of software called "Quikey" for more than 30 years. (I've only been here for the last 7.) It handles inventory, sales, customers, accounts receivable/payable, etc. Basically a sort of Quickbooks that's geared specifically for our industry (or so I've been told).

However, as you may surmise, this software is woefully outdated. It's a text-only based program that is running on an old version of RedHat Linux. It has no API of which I am aware. Product IDs are limited to 10 characters. There is no automation; everything gets entered/managed by hand by our customer service team. The list goes on. Here's a shot of the main screen (The "Quickey" in the window title is a typo):

[image: Quikey Screenshot]

From what our boss has told me, the tech support for this program has not responded to our repeated requests for help in over a year. Even [their web site](https://www.quikey-c.com/site) appears to be offline now, though it was working just a few months ago, as I recall.

As our company is now getting a new web site developed with WordPress, we would like to have a more modern setup overall, as well, which means replacing this outdated crap with something modern that can ideally plug into WordPress/WooCommerce. I do not know much about business software, but I know that a modern CRM is at least part of the solution.

Can someone please offer up some recommendations for modern software that can replace Quikey altogether? Something that is made for the promotional products decorating industry?

For a better idea of what our company does, please take a look at our equally-woefully-outdated web site of our main dba, [American Accents](https://americanaccents.com).

Comment: I do hope you’re able to find a replacement. That seems pretty niche. If you have manuals for the product, I would be interested in figuring out whether there’s something that can be customized to your needs or possibly quote you what it would take to do a custom application for you. There are many good CRM out there. You may want to just find one close to meeting your needs and go from there. Sorry I don’t have better news. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for commenting, @WilfredSmith. Do you think that all we need is just a general-purpose CRM? Is that what a CRM does: all of the tasks that a business needs, including accounting, inventory, etc.? I apologize for being completely new the term and not knowing much about it except that it stands for "Customer Relationship Management" and that Salesforce and HubSpot are two big players in the field.

Comment: If you go for something like Salesforce CRM, there are modules for everything you can imagine. Lesser CRM will have some degree of programmability.